# Autosys box condition: Run if last run of box is success

Tags: autosys

Have a box which has 10 jobs. The box is scheduled to run everyday after every 1 hour say at 9, 10, 11... There are no conditions on any jobs within the box nor on the box.

When the last job fails say at 9:30, the box becomes failed.
When one of the middle job fails say at 9:30, the box remains in running state.

Now at the next run time comes ie 10:
In case of last job failure, the box restarts at 10.
In case of mid job failure, the box doesn't restart.

In case of last job failure, I want the box not to restart at 10 as we want the whole box to be completed or wait for someone to fix the last job.

How can I do that? Is there a way to put a condition on box that it starts only when last run of the box is success. Would the condition success(box_name) be appropriate? Please help. Let me know in case the issue is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

In that case create a 11th job in main box with job_type: b and sleep_interval: 60

and change success condition of main box to success(job11).

Make job11 as dependent to job10, where job 11 runs after success(Job10).

If job10 fails, work on the failure and needs to trigger job11 for the mainbox to succeed.